# Program gives same result every time when it should be random

Tags: java, reduce, pi

The goal of this program is to take 2 random variables for a fraction and see if they are already in reduced terms or not. The supposed probability of this is 6/(pi^2). I run 1,000 different combinations of variables and determine how many were and were not already reduced. Then I solve for pi.

But the output is giving me "pi is 2.449489742783178" every time I run it.

Anyone know why? Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ratio1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int nonReducedCount = 0; //counts how many non reduced ratios there are
        for(int i =1; i<=1000; i++){

            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;  //random int creation
            int m = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
            //Ratio ratio = new Ratio(n,m);
            if (gcd(n,m)> 1 ){ // if the ratio was not already fully reduced
                nonReducedCount++; // increase the count of non reduced ratios
            }   
        }

        int reducedCount = 1000 - nonReducedCount; //number of times the ratio was reduced already
        double reducedRatio = reducedCount / nonReducedCount; //the ratio for reduced and not reduced
        reducedRatio *= 6;
        reducedRatio = Math.sqrt(reducedRatio);
        System.out.println("pi is " + reducedRatio);
    }

    public static int gcd(int a, int b) { return b==0 ? a : gcd(b,a%b); }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you divide two integers, you get integer division, with an integer result, even if you later assign the result to a `double`.  Try

```
double reducedRatio = (double)reducedCount / nonReducedCount;
```

i.e. convert one of the operands to a `double`.